# When is it objectively the right time to give up on someone?

Tags: ethics, hope

Do we have an obligation to give up on some people? You know the sort of thing I mean: this person does *not* love you, is only here to exploit you, has no sense of fairness/justice, is shallow and self centred, is and only ever was using you, etc.. What if they are the victim of extreme tragedy, madness and deception? What can we do?

Comment: When?  *"Meditate on this, I will."* ~ Master Yoda

Comment: "there is no" "objectively", so "never" 

Answer (score 0):

I worked out the answer: it depends. Someone is always worth something (even if that someone is yourself) or at least most things. Is who you are asking about the best candidate for that?

Though that person must not be seeking your annihilation, spiritual or material, else your 'love' is not reciprocated, and they would rather be your enemy. Mind you, courtly love of all sorts must be a very hypocritical device, so take this paragraph with a grain of salt.

And no, people who seek to use you, for wealth, celebrity, whatever, are not worthy of your love, spiritual or otherwise (though I suppose they may be worth working for lol).